# TestCafe throws an References error for a page element that is not being used in tests

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I just started to look into this test automation tool called "testCafe". Here is the tool details: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/

In my first test, I am navigating through 2 pages using deep URLs. Here is a scenario
1) Hit the home page URL
2) Navigate to another page using another URL
3) Perform assertion on page 2

I get the following error:
***1) Error on page "https://page2url.com":

      ReferenceError: initFooterSiteSwitcher is not defined***

Here is my code- firsttest.js

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import Page from './homepage-model';
import finAdv from './finAdvisorpage-model';

const page = new Page();
const page_finAdv = new finAdv();


fixture `Getting Started`
.page `https://homepageurl.com`;

test('My first test', async t =>{
    await t
    .navigateTo('page2url.com')    
    .click(page_finAdv.gottoLink)
    .expect(page_finAdv.linktext).eql('Sample text');

});
```

I looked in the DOM for page2url.com and I found this function in the DOM: initFooterSiteSwitcher(). But as you can see, I am not interacting with this in my test yet I get an error and the test won't move on to the next steps in the test case. Could someone please share some insight on it. Is this an HTML problem with the app itself or my test?

Comment: If you search their github, that function does not show up so it's most likely a problem with your site. when you load your site and open F12 (developer tools chrome) does it show the same error.

Comment: you should add the option `--skip-js-errors` on the TestCafe command-line to prevent TestCafe to stop execution when a JS error occurs on the tested web page.

Comment: appreciate the quick response. That helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the app. To check it, open DevTools in your browser, navigate to the page without TestCafe, and check the output in the Console tab.

If you can see the error in the Console tab without TestCafe, and the website still works properly, you can ignore this error when running tests by using the `-e` switch: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-e---skip-js-errors

If the error doesn't appear without TestCafe, it can be caused by a bug in TestCafe. In this case you can submit a bug report to the TestCafe repository: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md

Comment: Thanks. yes, I checked the console and there seems to be an error in the console. So, I used this "testcafe chrome test.js -e" as my run command.Thanks for the help!